# DateTime in winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I have the following code within the class.

basically what i need is it to tell me the current DateTime.

where i have a problem is when compiling, as under the dateTime code there is syntax error 
saying: "The type 'dateAndTime' already contains a definition for 'dateTime'"

```
 class dateAndTime
        {
            public dateAndTime dateTime { get; private set; }

            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();

            DateTime dateTime;

        }
    }
```

can anyone help with this problem please?

much appreciated!

Comment: You defined dateTime variable three times. You can do it only one time

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: it says i can only select an answer in 3 minutes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three lines are declaring variables (or properties):

```
public dateAndTime dateTime { get; private set; }
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
DateTime dateTime;
```

No two elements in a class definition can have the same name.

What are you trying to accomplish that can't be done with `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: Thanks all.. BrokenGlass's answer has helped me now

Answer (score 1):

Just add property to your class( actually you need [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)):

```
public DateTime CurrentDateTime
{
  get
    {
      return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> basically what i need is it to tell me the current DateTime.

You don't need your class at all. Just use [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx).

Comment: Its amazing how the so simple is often not the obvious solution.  Why use some class / property to get what DateTime.Now already provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redeclare a variable with the same name as the property name:

```
class MyDateAndTime
{

   public DateTime dateTime { get; private set; }

   public MyDateAndTime()
   {
                dateTime = new DateTime();

   }
}
```